# Fetch IP addresses of all the running containers from inside docker container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm, docker-network

I'm running multiple containers on multiple hosts using docker overlay network and swarm services. All the containers are connected to the same docker network, I can communicate between them with their alias name.

Assume a scenario:

```
Host1 -> container1: alias=conA. ip: 10.0.0.4
Host2 -> container2: alias=conB, ip: 10.0.0.5
Host3 -> container3: alias=conB, ip: 10.0.0.6
```

from inside container1, if I do *gethostbyname(conB)* it gives ip of either container2 or container3.

As a work around, I run *gethostbyname(conB)* until I get 2 unique IP addresses.

What I'm looking for is to get a container_name:ip_address table for all the containers connected to this network

Comment: I think docker resolves service hostname requests with multiple containers behind with a round robin style resolution.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using zmq for communication. So if I do connect by alias it'll connect to one of them then zmq cant communicate to other container.

Comment: You could use a service discovery tool like consul.

Answer (score 0):

I assume container 2 and 3 are two replicas of a single service? In that case you can lookup the hostname name for `tasks.servicename` to get the 2 ip addresses.